# Unsupported Media Type Spring ReST resource

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, resources

I have a simple method defined in my Rest Resource as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{studyId}/cases/{caseId}/exportlocation/{exportLocation}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@Timed
public void exportCase(@PathVariable Long studyId, @PathVariable Long caseId, @PathVariable String exportLocation,
        @RequestBody Case acase) throws Exception {
    log.debug("REST request to export Case {} for Study : {}", acase, studyId);
    String exportFileName = exportService.exportCase(acase, "test");
    // if (exportFileName == null) {
    // response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "Can't Export");
    // }
    // return exportFileName;
}
```

When I make a call on the page, I can see the URL as being `/app/rest/studies/1/cases/1/exportlocation/test`

I have the Request Mapping defined as

```
@RequestMapping(value = StudyResource.REQUEST_MAPPING, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Secured(AuthoritiesConstants.USER)
public class StudyResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StudyResource.class);

    public static final String REQUEST_MAPPING = "/app/rest/studies";
```

But keep getting a 415 Unsupported Media type. Can someone please look at the lines of code and tell me what is wrong. I highly appreciate your time and help.
My JS layer from where the calls are made on the page are as shown"

```
 $scope.exportCase = function(studyId, caseId, exportLocation){
                 StudyService.updatecase.get({studyId:studyId,caseId:caseId}).$promise.then(function(acase){
             $scope.acase = acase;
             console.log(acase);
         });
        StudyService.exportcase.exportc({studyId: studyId,caseId:caseId,exportLocation:exportLocation},$scope.acase,
        function () {
```

AND JS Service part below

```
exportcase : $resource('app/rest/studies/:studyId/cases/:caseId/exportlocation/:exportLocation', {}, {
        'exportc' : {
            method : 'PUT',
            params : {
                studyId : '@studyId',
                caseId : '@caseId',
                exportLocation : '@exportLocation'
            }
        },
    })
```

Comment: How do you call the relevant URL? Can you show us that piece of code?

Comment: [[Angular JS Service]]exportcase : $resource('app/rest/studies/:studyId/cases/:caseId/exportlocation/:exportLocation', {}, {
   'exportc' : {
    method : 'POST',
    params : {
        studyId : '@studyId',
        caseId : '@caseId',
        exportLocation : '@exportLocation'
    }
   },
  }),

Comment: [[Angular Controller Call]]         $scope.exportCase = function(studyId, caseId, exportLocation){
          
         StudyService.exportcase.exportc({studyId: studyId,caseId:caseId,exportLocation:exportLocation},$scope.acase,
            function () {

Comment: You need to add that to the question as its important.

Comment: Just did but no answer